# Dialog from click on control in list view

Tags: android, listview, datepicker, dialog

What is best practice to show dialog (like date picker) on control thats in Listview view?

Is it OK to create custom control that embeds dialog logic and place it into Listview views?

EDIT:

For example:
I have textEdit that is placed in Listview. I want to show date picker when user click the textEdit. I want to know what is the best place to put dialog logic to.

Comment: can't understand your quetion, please explain more and clean

Comment: I updated the question. Please let me know what is not clear in my question.

Comment: you can display dialog when user click on edittext

Comment: yes but that edittext is placed in list view. So should i put the logic into activity/fragment where the list view is placed?

Comment: did you try it inside listview adapter ?

Comment: Yup I can do it in adapter or by creating my own control. But I wasn't sure what is best practice. I'll go with adapter. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setOnItemClickListener` in your adapter logic for the `ListView`.

You then need to create an instance of `OnItemClickListener` and override the `OnClick()` method and perform your click logic there. Below is a very simple example to demonstrate this concept.

```
public class MySimpleListAdapter implements ListAdapter {

    // Set your constructors and so on

    . . . 

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.simple_row_layout, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.simple_text_view);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (adapterData != null) {
            viewHolder.textView.setText(item.getTaskTitle()); // This is logic from my SQ Lite database
            viewHolder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Implement your logic for launching a DialogFragment here
                }
            });
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Then finally, in your `Activity` where you're displaying the `ListView`, just set the `MySimpleListAdapter` to your `ListView` and you should be good to go.

My code above uses a `TextView` widget instead of an `EditText`, but it should be simple enough to replace it with the `EditText` widget.